# Jmeter Pre/Post Processor

Tags: apache, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

In JMeter, do Pre/Post Processors (e.g 'JDBD') affect the response time for the request?
For 'View Results in Table' listener, will the "Sample Time" be impacted with JDBC processors?

Answer (score 2):

Pre/Post Processors and Timers execution time is **not included** into response time (unless you use [Transaction Controller](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) in "Parent Sampler" mode and explicitly tell it to store pre/post processors and timers footprint)

Comment: Just one more concern please, if the pre/ post processor was under the test plan but out side the thread group. Will these processors be executed for each thread group or only once at the test start?

Comment: It will be executed before each sampler by each thread in each loop